# Why does P(A,B) notation sometimes cause an addition and sometimes cause a multiplication?

Tags: probability

I am trying to understand these notes on a whiteboard

$P(A,B) = P(A)+P(B) - P(A\cap B)$
if $A,B$ are independent $P(A\cap B)= P(A) P(B)$

I can understand the first equation by thinking of Venn Diagram with circles A and B overlapping.
For the second equation I think of a Venn Diagram with the circles not overlapping. But why would I be multiplying instead of adding?

To add to my confusion, I sometimes see $A\cap B$ written as $AB$

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by $P(A,B)$.

Comment: * not clear  what the author meant. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is on one whiteboard, the instructor made a typographical error, or someone transcribed or interpreted the whiteboard incorrectly.  There is variation in the meaning of $P(A,B)$, but those are clearly two different meanings.

The first "$A,B$" means "$A$ or $B$", or $A \cup B$, i.e. $A$ union $B$, for events that are not necessarily disjoint.

The second "$A,B$" means "$A$ and $B$" or $A\cap B$, i.e. $A$ intersect $B$, in the case where $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Sometimes people write "$A$ and $B$" or $A\cap B$ as $AB$.  Sometimes people use the comma for this.  Sometimes comma is used for conditional probability.  I've never seen the comma for disjunction or union, as in the first example, but as I said, there is variation.

(To visualize the second equation, don't use circles.  Use a rectangle divided vertically and horizontally.  What's on one side of the vertical line is $A$, and what's on one side of the horizontal line is $B$.  That's independence.  Non-independence would be represented using a diagonal line or a line with steps in it.)